# Creating drop down menu from database Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create drop down menu. 
database tables:

```
*cat*

catid, catname, catsex

*menus*

id,parrentid,name,icon,slug,number
```

menu code in view

```
echo $this->multi_menu->render(array(

        'nav_tag_open'        => '<ul class="nav nav-pills">',    

        'parentl1_tag_open'   => '<li class="dropdown">',

        'parentl1_anchor'     => '<a tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown" href="%s">%s<span class="caret"></span></a>',

        'parent_tag_open'     => '<li class="dropdown-submenu">',

        'parent_anchor'       => '<a href="%s" data-toggle="dropdown">%s</a>',
        'children_tag_open'   => '<ul class="dropdown-menu">',
        'item_active'         => 'Gallery/foto'
    ));
```

menu code in controler Gallery:

```
$this->load->model('Gallery_model', 'menu');

        $items = $this->menu->every();

        $this->load->library("multi_menu");

        $this->multi_menu->set_items($items);
```

menu code in model Gallery_model

```
public function every()
    {
        return $this->db->get("menus")
                    ->result_array();
    }
```

Now I will try to explain what is my question.
I want to create dropdown menu item, where all cats names are shown (I want get these names from database table) and if I change any cat name record in database, it should be changed in menu item too. Something like that

```
Cats Female
Adorada Amor
Dani Vitala

Cats Male
Glant Diamo
Lorris Diatore
Paol Duece
```

Where names are from database table cat.
Any help how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this.

**In Controller:**

```
public function abc()
    {
        $data['plan_data']=$this->plan_model->view_plan();

        $this->load->view('templates/header',$header);
        $this->load->view('xyz',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

**In Model:**

```
public function view_plan()
{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM your table";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

**In View:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="plan_type" required>
                                <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($plan_data as $plan){
                                    if($plan['plan_id']==$select_plan){
                                ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $plan['plan_id'];?>" selected><?php echo $plan['plan_name'];?></option>
                                <?php
                                    }else{
                                ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $plan['plan_id'];?>"><?php echo $plan['plan_name'];?></option>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
```

This may help you.

Comment: I understand what you are offering, but can I put this code in my menu with other items, I have already created?If so, where should I put your view in my view code, because this select option should be near other menu items?
If I understand correctly, I should put your view code somewhere in view code, which I have posted earlier. But where?